# can't assign to operator while using argparse

Tags: python-3.x

*So i was trying to do project based on argparse. And actually I copied all the code down below from sentdex, who has a channel on Youtube.
     But for some reason code of mine doesn't work and his does.
     I'd be really happy if someone helped me, because it's so pissing off)*

```
import argparse
import sys

def main():
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--x', type=float,default=1.0,
                        help='What is the first number?')
    parser.add_argument('--y', type=float,default=1.0,
                        help='What is the second number?')
    parser.add_argument('--operation', type=str,default='sub',
                        help='What operation? (add, sub, )')
    args=parser.parse_args()
    sys.stdout.write(str(calc(args)))

def calc(args):
    operation=args.operation
    x = args.x
    y = args.y
    if operation == 'add':
        return x + y
    elif operation == 'sub':
        return x - y
if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
#console:

--x=2 --y=4 --operation=sub
 File "<ipython-input-1-f108b29d54dc>", line 1
   --x=2 --y=4 --operation=sub
                           ^
 SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argparse` parses `sys.argv`, which is meant to be initialized from running the script in the command line, but you're running this from iPython, so it's treating sub as a built-in operator function.

You should either run this as a script from the command line, or modify `args=parser.parse_args()` to:

```
args=parser.parse_args(['--x', '2', '--y', '4', '--operation', 'sub'])
```

if you just want to test it without running the script from the command line.